# PHP Array Building - How to write it better

Tags: php, arrays

Been racking my brains on how to write this better AND make it loop depending on the $count value:

```
    if($count == 2){
        $thenode = $tree[$splitnode[0]][$splitnode[1]];
    } elseif($count == 3){
        $thenode = $tree[$splitnode[0]][$splitnode[1]][$splitnode[2]];
    }
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: What is the maximum count you need? You might want to use recursion.

Comment: I think you need to flatten your $tree array so that you're less dependent on the dimensional numbers beyond 2.

Comment: I don't no the answer to that but $count has the maximum value.

Answer (score 0):

```
$thenode = $tree;

for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $thenode = $thenode[$splitnode[$i]];
}

var_dump($thenode);
```

or

```
$thenode = array_reduce(
    range(0, $count - 1),
    function ($thenode, $i) use ($splitnode) { return $thenode[$splitnode[$i]]; },
    $tree
);
```

or maybe

```
$thenode = $tree;

foreach ($splitnode as $i => $sn) {
    if ($i >= $count) {
        break;
    }
    $thenode = $thenode[$sn];
}
```